# How can I exchange a small amount of USD to INR?

Tags: india, usd-us-dollar, inr-indian-rupee

My grandma has gifted me 20 US dollars. How can I exchange it for Indian rupees? I don’t have a passport or pan card. I have tried a few forex sites and they asked for a passport but I don’t have a passport.

Comment: Do you have 20USD as paper money, a card, or an electronic format?

Answer (score 2):

If the 20 dollars is in cash (US currency), you can try using a physical currency exchange shop if they exist in your area. Unfortunately the fees may be relatively high on this small amount. You can also see if a shop where you want to make a purchase will accept US dollars, or perhaps exchange with a family member or friend who wants US dollars.

Comment: Another possibility would be to keep it until you (or someone you know) needs USD.